# Angularjs value service & factory service

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

In angular [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value)

> Register a value service with the $injector, such as a string, a number, an array, an object or a function. This is short for registering a service where its **provider's $get property is a factory function that takes no arguments and returns the value service**.

In the bold text, that says `$get property is a factory function that takes no arguments`, I know about the `$get` function in a `angular providers` which will be invoked using `$injector.invoke()` when an instance needs to be created and it is must have a `$get` function in a provider.

my question is about what is the underlying meaning of `function that takes no arguments`?

much appreciate if someone can describe the inner pieces of the `angular` `values service` & `factory service` with comparing both with the above doc quote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means angular is creating a provider, like any other, that returns the value you're passing to it with `module.value('name', value);`. This type of provider is appropriate when there is no logic involved in building the value, and no dependency on some other service.

Comparison, yielding same result:

---

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .value('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:8080/');
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('baseUrl', baseUrlFactory);

function baseUrlFactory(){
    return 'http://localhost:8080/';
}
```